# How to use a struct without initializing its members?

Tags: rust, struct, initialization, member

I'm trying to use a struct without initializing some of its members, to be able to use it:

```rust
struct Structure {
    initialized: bool,
    data: StructureData, // This is another struct...
    target: TargetTrait, // This member that I don't need to initialize.
}

impl Structure {
    pub fn initialize(&mut self) -> bool {
        if self.initialized {
            false
        } else {
            // Here I should initialize the target...
            self.target = initializeTarget(...); // No problem...
            self.initialized = true;
            true
        }
    }

    pub fn new(&self) -> Structure {
        Structure {
            initialized: false,  // The initialize method will do that...
            data: StructureData, // Initializing Structure data behind the
            // scenes...
            // Here the struct needs some value for the target, but I cannot provide any value,
            // Because the initialization method will do that job...
            target: None, // I tried using (None), and Option<T>,.
                          // But the TargetTrait refused.
        }
    }
}

// main function:
fn main() {
    let structure: Structure = Structure::new(); // It should construct a new structure...
    if structure.initialize() {
        // Here, I should do some work with the target...
    }
}
```

I tried to use Option, but the target trait doesn't implement Option, or even

```
#[derive(Default)]
```

Comment: What do you mean by the target trait? If you are constrained by a trait and that is the real reason for your question then please also include the trait in your question.

Comment: @Peter Hall, That trait is an external library!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be solved using the [Typestate](http://cliffle.com/blog/rust-typestate/) pattern, under the form of a builder type.

The basic idea behind this pattern is that invalid states shouldn't be representable at runtime (eg. by changing the value of the `initialized` field, in this case).
Instead this should be handled by the type system at compile time.

For example, here you'd use two distinct types.
A first "uninitialised" builder type that represents the state of the structure without the `target` present, and the initialized `Structure` containing the target. It does not contain an `initialized` field though, since by virtue of being built by the other class, it can only represent an initialized state (hence the **Type State**).

```
struct Structure {
    data: StructureData,
    target: TargetTrait,
}

struct StructureBuilder {
    data: StructureData,
}

impl StructureBuilder {
    pub fn initialize(self) -> Structure {
        // Here I should initialize the target...
        Structure {
            data: self.structureData,
            target: initializeTarget(),
        }
    }

    pub fn new() -> StructureBuilder {
        StructureBuilder {
            data: StructureData, // Initializing Structure data behind the scenes
        }
    }
}
```

This type takes care of initializing the `target` with the initialize method.

However, the method signature (taking self by value) makes sure that the instance of `StructureBuilder` cannot be reused afterwards, and the newly created `Structure` takes ownership of the data being moved into it.

It would then be used like this:

```
fn main() {
    let builder = StructureBuilder::new();
    let structure = builder.initialize();
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `&self` argument in the definition of `StructureBuilder::new`